# Why do we need to provide weather conditions in ID questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was kind of surprised to see that in one of [_ID question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/38986/8986) someone provided weather conditions that occurred during the moment when picture in question was taken.

Why do we need to provide such data? If weather conditions would be completely different, would that impact identification process in any way?

Comment: I don't see a reason to regulary include this information. Only if it would be important for the identification. And it is the first question of this kind I remember which has this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very helpful tag page for species identification questions:

https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info

There is no requirement there for detailed weather information.

There is a note to include:

> Additional useful info (e.g., behavior, time of day/year, etc...)

as a catch-all category that could potentially include weather, but in most cases *specific* weather information is probably not necessary. However, the behavior of some organisms (especially whether they are likely to be encountered by people..) is weather-dependent, and weather *could* help identification in those cases. That said, I see no need to include weather information regularly, the vast majority of species ID questions have no such information.